# Kolla ansible images pull error on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ansible, openstack

I'm trying to deployement an Openstack infrastracture multi node with kolla-ansible on `Ubuntu 20.04.4`.

```
ansible 4.10.0 
ansible-core 2.11.11 
kolla-ansible  13.0.1
```

when I execute command:

```
kolla-ansible -i /etc/kolla/multinode pull
```

or

```
kolla-ansible -i /etc/kolla/multinode deploy
```

I'm getting error:

> fatal: [controller]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host'.. String: {{ lookup('vars', (kolla_role_name | default(project_name)) + '_services') | select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host }}"}
>
> fatal: [compute01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host'.. String: {{ lookup('vars', (kolla_role_name | default(project_name)) + '_services') | select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host }}"}

```
I have 1 deployment Node, 1 controller, 1 compute Node
```

Comment: `No filter named 'select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host'` <= I strictly have no idea where this custom jinja2 filter is supposed to be defined and what is the openstack/kolla/whatever documented way to have it installed but I know for sure it is not available in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems like a pull-issue based in the error-message. Seems like another configuration-problem with your Neutron. The default-multi-node config requires 3 controller. I don't exactly know your multi-node config for kolla-ansible, but when you only want 1 controller and 1 compute you can do something different:

Use the `all-in-one`-file for your setup. Should be in path `kolla-ansible/ansible/inventory/all-in-one`. Modify this file by replacing the `localhost` in the `[compute]`-section with the name of the host, where the compute should be created and remove the `ansible_connection=local`. This always worked for me, when I created a test-deployment with 1 controller and X compute-nodes.

Only in case you want the controller not on the host, where you execute the kolla-ansible, then replace all other `localhost` by the name of your controller-node and of course remove the `ansible_connection=local` everywhere.

Only the be sure: Don't forget to write the name of the host with it's ip-address in the `/etc/hosts`-file on the node, where you execute the kolla-ansible run.

Comment: I strongly doubt fixing the inventory will make a missing custom jinja2 filter suddenly available.

Comment: I also had strange errors with kolla-ansible in the past. My theory is, that his multi-node-config doesn't match with the physical available deployment, which results into this error. Maybe there are host-name the in the file defined, which doesn't exist in reality, which breaks the jinja2-build-process. I have no time and resources at the moment to test it by myself. This here is the best possible guess I could give based on my experiences with kolla-ansible.

Comment: I get the same error with all-in-one deployment.

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host'.. String: {{ lookup('vars', (kolla_role_name | default(project_name)) + '_services') | select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host }}"}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what's the result of `kolla-ansible prechecks -i multinode_or_all-in-one` command?

Dive into this method `select_services_enabled_and_mapped_to_host` of `kolla-ansible` project, you will find some clues. The method's return dependent by [**`service_enabled`**](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/e9adef6fe087eee8cfaed41e774fec9390295d17/kolla_ansible/filters.py#L22) and [**`service_mapped_to_host`**](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/e9adef6fe087eee8cfaed41e774fec9390295d17/kolla_ansible/filters.py#L38)

So, there are two step to clear your problem:

- 1, check the service enabled setting in **/etc/kolla/globals.yml** and **kolla-ansible/ansible/group_vars/all.yml**.

> You can use this file(globals.yml) to override *any* variable throughout Kolla. Additional options can be found in the 'kolla-ansible/ansible/group_vars/all.yml' file.

- 2, check the host [**inventory**](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/multinode.html#edit-the-inventory-file) in **multinode** or **all-in-one** file whether consistent with the really information or not.

Or everything is OK, I think you should redeploy it refer to **[kolla-ansible quickstar](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html)**.

Comment: No error return with ``kolla-ansible prechecks -i multinode_or_all-in-one``